# c# windows app with progress bar

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a datagridview with data and I am exporting it to excel, which takes some time, in the mean time(export is going on) I just want to show a progress bar. How can I achieve this? I used backgroundworker and was unsuccessful, as the progressbar progress after completion of the export functionality.

Comment: Give us some code please

Comment: I have a menu item Export and on click of menu item i am calling method. Parallel I want a progress bar progressing.....  I tried various ways and the code is clumsy so not sending that...                      ExcelImportExport excelobj = new ExcelImportExport();
            bool exportStatus = excelobj.ExportToExcel(dgvResource);

Comment: Don't put your code in the comment, put it in your question details

Comment: What sort of application is this ? Windows (WinForms/WPF) or web (WebForms/MVC)?

Comment: Simple windows application (winforms)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue **without using any thread or backgroundworker**.  I simply set the maximum property of progressbar to the datagridview.Rows.Count and incremented the value of toolstripstatusbar when ever a single row is written to excel file. It resolved my problem.

```
tsProgBar.Maximum = dgvResource.Rows.Count;

//loop from 1 to dgvResource.rows.count
{
//code to write a row to excel...
tsProgBar.Value = tsProgBar.Value + 1;
}
```